# Making a field accessible to sunspot for ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Assets have a list of statuses and a number. My goal is to use [sunspot](http://sunspot.github.io) to add searchability and to sort on the status and number. In my Asset model I have:

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  ⋮
  searchable do
    text :statuses do
      statuses.map(&:name)
    end
   ⋮
```

Then in my assets controller I have:

```
Asset.search do
  ⋮
  order_by :statuses, :desc
end
```

When I try to run it I get an error:

```
Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError in SearchController#assets

No field configured for Asset with name 'statuses'
```

The definition in the `searchable` section of the asset model is configuring a field, right?

I also tried adding a `join` to the list of statuses to convert it to a string, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Sunspot can't order by a field you index as text. But you can order with strings.

Instead of:

```
text :statuses do
  statuses.map(&:name)
end
```

Try:

```
string :statuses do
  statuses.map(&:name)
end
```